# How to make list the elements of a list

Tags: python, list, multidimensional-array

I have to make a list of the elements of a list.
I have the list:
`n=[1,2,3,4,5,6]`
and I want to create:

```
n=[[1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6]]
n=[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]
n=[[1,2,3],[4,5,6]]
```

I can do the first one using map(list,n), but what about the others?
Also if I want to create a list for each couple of elements, like:

```
n=[[1,2] [2,3] [3,4] [4,5] [5,6]]
```

How can I do that?

Comment: The chunkify() code in this post seems to be what you’re finding: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47900922/5517838

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It is important for the community that you demonstrate that you are *also* working to solve your issue. the best way to do that is to include the **text** based source you have so far, even if it is not working quite right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a chunkify method using some list comprehension, iter and zip trick:

```py
def chunkify(l, size):
    it = iter(l)
    return [list(e) for e in zip(*[it for _ in range(size)])]
```

example:

```py
n=[1,2,3,4,5,6]
for size in range(1, 4):
    print(chunkify(n, size))
```

outputs:

```
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> s = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
>>> s1 = [[each] for each in s]
>>> s1
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6]]

>>> s2 = [[each,each+1] for each in s[:2:]]
>>> s2

[[1, 2], [2, 3]]
>>> s2 = [[each,each+1] for each in s[::2]]
>>> s2
[[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6]]
>>> s2 = [[each, each+1, each+2] for each in s[::3]]
>>> s2

[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]]
>>>
```